# Stochastic discount factor (aka deflator or pricing kernel) and class D processes

Tags: stochastic-calculus, pricing, no-arbitrage-theory

When (under what assumptions on the model) does a [Stochastic Discount Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_discount_factor) need to be [of Class D](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/class-d-processes/)? What would be the implications if it was not? Is it connected to one of the no-arbitrage notions?